# Magento admin Base table or view not found

Tags: error, table

I'm moving a magento website over to a new server, I'm getting this error trying to access admin.

There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cmodz_control_data_7_10.mag2013ves_pdfpro_apikey' doesn't exist

Not much experience with Magento, so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because the module Ves Pdfpro did not get moved correctly. Rename its xml file in app/etc/modules folder so that it's not an xml file after that. You'll get a working admin.

Now, to move that extension correctly, you'll need to check the database to see if it's resource is properly recorded in core_resource table. If it is, then check the folders of the module for correct copy.

If everything seems OK, then you might have to re-install the module(Easiest solution), delete record from core_resource table and then refresh your page.
But this way, you'll have a clean installation of module, any data you saved when working with the module will be lost. So, it will basically depend upon that module.