# Shows "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found----" when I try to access the customer details in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer-account

In admin panel manage customer section, when I click on the customer to view the details, there is an error page appear with the below contents. How can I solve this?

> There has been an error processing your request      SQLSTATE[42S02]:
>   Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'XXX.log_customer' doesn't
>   exist, query was: `` SELECT `log_customer`.*, `lvt`.`last_visit_at`, `lvit`.`http_referer`, `lvit`.`remote_addr`, `luit`.`url` FROM `log_customer`
>   INNER JOIN `log_visitor` AS `lvt` ON lvt.visitor_id = log_customer.visitor_id
>   INNER JOIN `log_visitor_info` AS `lvit` ON lvt.visitor_id = lvit.visitor_id
>   INNER JOIN `log_url_info` AS `luit` ON luit.url_id = lvt.last_url_id 
>   WHERE (`log_customer`.`customer_id`='50')
>   ORDER BY `log_customer`.`login_at` DESC LIMIT 1 ``
>
> Trace:
>   #0
>   lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>   #1
>   app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291):
>   Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>   #2
>   lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>   #3
>   lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `log_cus...', Array)
>   #4
>   lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `log_cus...', Array)
>   #5
>   lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
>
> #6
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(380):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
>   #7
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Customer),
>   '50', 'customer_id')
>   #8
>   app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Customer.php(71):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('50', 'customer_id')
>   #9
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View.php(69):
>   Mage_Log_Model_Customer->loadByCustomer('50')
>   #10
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View.php(108):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View->getCustomerLog()
>   #11
>   app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml(33):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View->getLastLoginDate()
>   #12
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include('a...')
>   #13
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
>   #14
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   #15
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   #16
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   #17
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   #18
>   app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View))
>
> #19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include('a...')
>   #20
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
>   #21
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   #22
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   #23
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   #24
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   #25
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
>   #26
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   #27
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
>   #28
>   app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
>   #29
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include('a...')
>   #30
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
>   #31
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   #32
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   #33
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   #34
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   #35
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
>   #36
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(151):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
>   #37
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->editAction()
>   #38
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
>   #39
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> #40 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   #41
>   app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   #42
>   index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
>   #43 {main}

I tried these links but didn't solve my problem.

- [Magento admin Base table or view not found](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78235/magento-admin-base-table-or-view-not-found)
- [SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111786/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78108/help-magento-error-in-file-sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-11

Comment: did upu check that this table exits or not???

Comment: Yeah, the table exist